# nerdctl compose do not support expose

Tags: nerdctl

docker-compose.yaml:

```
  mysql_db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerfileMySQL
    container_name: mysql_db_${TAG:-latest}
    image: mysql_db:${TAG:-latest}
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test1
    expose:
      - "3306"

  ...
```

but when i use `nerdctl compose up`，it would `WARN[0000] Ignoring: service mysql_db: [Expose]`，and the container would not expose port，so other container withing the same network could not access mysql_db